# "im" in Bezug zu einem Objekt

Tags: preposition

Der folgende Satz lässt sich auf zwei Weisen lesen:

- Ein Paar sitzt im Auto.
- Ein Paar sitzt in dem Auto.

Im zweiten Satz ist klar, dass beide Personen des "Paars" in dem selben Auto sitzen.
Der erste Satzt lässt jedoch Spielraum für Diskussionen.
Könnten hier beide Personen des "Paars" in zwei unterschiedlichen Autos sitzen?

Alternatives Beispiel: "Die Panzerbesatzung sitzt im Panzer." - ist eine generelle Aussage darüber, dass sich eine Panzerbesatzung in Panzern aufhält.

Comment: Du geht von einer falschen Prämisse aus. Es gibt keinen Spielraum für Diskussionen. Mehr dazu in meiner Antwort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der erste Satz lässt, im Gegensatz zu deiner Behauptung, keinerlei Spielraum für Diskussionen. Der erste Satz bedeutet ganz genau dasselbe wie der zweite, denn »im« bedeutet ganz genau dasselbe wie »in dem«.

»Im« ist nichts weiter als eine Kurzform von »in dem« (lokale Präposition + bestimmter Artikel Dativ Singular, männlich oder sächlich), so wie auch die folgenden Beispiele. (Bezüglich der Bestimmtheit beachte bitte den Nachtrag weiter unten):

- im = in dem
- am = an dem (in Österreich auch »auf dem«, z.B. »*St. Anton **am** Arlberg*«)
- beim = bei dem
- vom = von dem
- zum = zu dem

aber auch

- ins = in das
- ans = an das
- zur = zu der

(Auch hier ist der zweite Bestandteil ein bestimmter Artikel. *Das* ist Akkusativ Singular sächlich, *der* ist Dativ Singular weiblich)

Diese Wörter sind ohne Veränderung der Bedeutung austauschbar.

Ähnliches gibt es auch in anderen Sprachen (z.B. Englisch: don't = do not; can't = can not; ...)

---

Das gilt auch für:

> Die Panzerbesatzung sitzt im Panzer.
>   Die Panzerbesatzung sitzt in dem Panzer.

Beide Sätze bedeuten genau dasselbe. Auf dem ersten Blick sagen beide Sätze aus, dass die gesamte Besatzung in einem einzigen Panzer sitzt. Falls die Besatzung aber aus 100 Soldaten besteht (diese Information müsste der Kontext liefern), ist das unrealistisch, und muss wie folgt umgedeutet werden:

> Die Panzerbesatzung sitzt in den Panzern.

Das wäre übrigens ohnehin die korrektere Formulierung, und wäre, falls tatsächlich mehrere Panzer besetzt werden, den beiden obigen Sätzen vorzuziehen.

---

### Nachtrag

In den Kommentaren wurde zurecht kritisiert, dass »in dem« einen bestimmten Artikel enthält, während bei »im« unklar ist, ob der verkürzte Artikel bestimmt oder unbestimmt ist.

Daher ergänze ich:

Die folgenden Verschmelzungen können (zusätzlich zu den oben beschriebenen Formen) auch wie folgt interpretiert werden:

- im = in einem
- am = an einem (in Ö. auch »auf einem«)
- beim = bei einem
- vom = von einem
- zum = zu einem

einige Beispiele:

> (Handytelefonat)
>   *A:* Was ist das für ein Lärm? Wo bist du?
>   *B:* Ich bin **im** Zug. = Ich bin **in einem** Zug.
>
> Filet **vom** Almochsen an glasiertem Wurzelgemüse. = Fillet **von einem** Almochsen ...
>
> Du machst mich so wütend! Ich werde gleich **zum** Berserker. = ... **zu einem** Berserker.

Daher sind in den Beispielen aus der Frage auch diese Interpretationen möglich:

> Das Paar sitzt **in einem** Auto.
>   Die Panzerbesatzung sitzt **in einem** Panzer.

Die Frage, ob »*Ein Paar sitzt im Auto*« so gedeutet werden kann, dass die beiden Personen in verschiedenen Autos sitzen, ist aber trotzdem mit einem klaren *NEIN!* zu beantworten.

---

### Nachtrag 2

Alle hier beschriebenen Konglomerate bestehen aus einer Präposition und einem **Artikel**. Ich habe das oben präzisiert.

Comment: Hmm. Bin mir nicht sicher, ob das wirklich so einfach ist. "dem" kann zwei Dinge sein: Ein Artikel oder ein Demonstrativpronomen (="diesem") - Und ich denke, das ist der Hintergrund der Frage, nämlich ob das "dem" im "im" auch ein Demonstrativpronomen sein kann. Nein, kann es nicht:  "Das Paar sitzt in diesem Auto" ist aber schon was anderes als "Das Paar sitzt im Auto". Zugegeben, das ist spitzfindig.

Comment: @tofro hat Recht, die von dir und dem Duden aufgemachte Formel »im = in dem« ist falsch. Bei »Ein Paar sitzt _im_ Auto« ist das Auto unbestimmt (irgendeins; so könnte ein Witz beginnen), bei »in _dem_ Auto« ist es ein bestimmtes Auto, das vorher schon erwähnt wurde.

Comment: **Meistens** stimmt die Duden-Formel schon. Wie immer gibt's halt Ausnahmen wie z.B "im"s, die sich eben nicht nach "in dem" auflösen lassen oder sich sehr holprig anhören würden: *im Grunde ist es so...*, *im Gegenteil...*, oder *Das Haus ist im Bau*

Comment: @tofro: Meistens, ja, aber dann ist es keine Formel mehr. Um eine Formel zu widerlegen genügt bereits ein einziger Fall, für den sie nicht gilt. Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/im) lässt sich »im« grundsätzlich durch »in dem« ersetzen, und das ist eben falsch, mit »Ein Paar sitzt in dem Auto.« kann kein Witz beginnen.

Comment: Ich würde auch sagen, dass im heutigen Deutsch „in dem“ immer das Demonstrativpronomen enthält.

Comment: @CarstenS Gebe ich dir recht, steht auch so in meiner Antwort. Der Hörer sucht einen Grund, warum der Sprecher nicht "im" sagt und nimmt automatisch an, es wäre demonstrativ gemeint.

Answer (score 4):

Das kleine Wörtchen "dem" (bzw. seine Nominativform "der") kann im Deutschen  mindestens drei Bedeutungen bzw. Funktionen haben:

1. Ein simpler Artikel
2. ein Demonstrativpronomen (=*dieser*). Um als Demonstrativpronomen zu funktionieren, muss es im Satz *betont* sein, sozusagen als Fingerzeig.
3. Ein Relativpronomen (der Mann, der aus der Kälte kam)

In deinem Beispielsatz kann das "dem", je nach Betonung und Kontext entweder (1) oder (2) sein.

> (1) Das Paar sitzt in dem Auto

("dem" unbetont) - eine ganz normale Aussage, die Leute sitzen halt im Auto.

> (2) Das Paar sitzt in **dem** Auto

(betontes "dem" = "diesem") demonstrativ, sie sitzen in *genau diesem* Auto, auf das ich möglicherweise sogar noch zeige.

Wie H.S. richtig schreibt, ist "im" ganz grundsätzlich eine Zusammenziehung aus "in" und "dem", allerdings nur, wenn "dem" als Artikel genutzt wird - Für die Bedeutung (2) funktioniert die Zusammenziehung nicht, da die erforderliche Betonung dadurch verlorenginge. Eine Betonung der Zusammenziehung "im" würde dazu führen, dass wir ausdrücken, dass das Paar **in** dem Auto (und nicht z.B. auf dem Dach) sitzt.

In einigen Fällen wird "im" auch so aufgefasst, als ob es aus "in" und einem *unbestimmten Artikel* zusammengezogen wäre. Dein Beispiel mit den Panzern (ich nehme lieber Schiffe...) geht in diese Richtung:

> Eine Schiffsbesatzung arbeitet in einem Maschinenraum eines Schiffes
>
> Die Schiffsbesatzung arbeitet im (in dem) Maschinenraum des Schiffes

Ich denke, wenn man den ersten Fall (beliebige Besatzung, beliebiges Schiff und beliebiger Maschinenraum) meint, darf man genaugenommen keinen bestimmten Artikel verwenden, und dann auch nicht zusammenziehen (*Eine Schiffsbeaatzung arbeitet <s>im</s> in einem Maschinenraum eines Schiffes*). Die Artikel sollten dann, der Klarheit zuliebe, alle unbestimmt sein.

"im" ist *normalerweise* wie oben schon erwähnt, eine Zusammenziehung, die sich *normalerweise* auch wieder trennen läßt. Es gibt allerdings Fälle, wo dieses Trennen nicht mehr möglich ist, weil die Zusammenziehung schon zu einer Standardphrase geworden ist. Ein paar Beispiele:

> *im* Grunde bin ich mir bewußt dass ...
>
> nein, *im* Gegenteil ist es so, daß ...
>
> Das  Haus ist *im* Bau.

In diesem Beispielen würde eine Trennung dazu führen, dass das "dem" demonstrativ aufgefaßt würde, was in vielen Fällen keinen Sinn ergibt. Das Zusammenziehen von Artikel und Präposition ist so üblich geworden, dass eine Trennung automatisch als Demonstrativpronomen aufgefasst wird.

Deine Vermutung "das Paar sitzt im Auto" könnte aufgefasst werden als "beide sitzen in unterschiedlichen Autos" wäre möglich, würde aber sicher nicht genau so ausgedrückt werden, weil es mißverständlich ist - "die beiden sitzen in ihren Autos" würde diese Tatsache vollkommen unmissverständlich ausdrücken. Das Deutsche ist hier nicht ganz so streng wie das Englische, das in einem solchen Fall (es handelt sich ja um mehrere Autos) zwingend Plural für die Autos verlangt. Deutsch ist ein wenig "schlampiger" und lebt mit der Mehrdeutigkeit:

> Jeden Morgen fahren Tausende von Menschen mit ihrem Auto zur Arbeit.

Alleine schon über die Anzahl ist klar, dass es sich hier wohl um mehrere Autos handeln muss.

> Jeden Morgen fahren Tausende von Menschen mit ihren Autos zur Arbeit.

wäre richtiger, logischer und auch durchaus empfehlenswerter, vor allem, wenn es sich um eine Anzahl handeln würde, die u.U. noch in ein Auto passen würde.

Answer (score 1):

Die Annahme, die in Deiner Frage steckt, ist im Grunde richtig. In Deinen konkreten Beispielen sind die beiden Varianten aber inhaltlich praktisch äquivalent.

Betrachten wir zunächst

> Alice und Bob liegen im Bett.

Ob es sich hier um ein oder zwei Betten handelt, wissen wir erst, wenn die Geschichte weitergeht und wir erfahren, ob Alice und Bob ein Liebespaar sind oder zwei Geschwister, die sich vor dem Einschlafen noch Geschichten erzählen, im selben Zimmer jedes in seinem Bett liegend. Wie der Satz verstanden wird, hängt von Kontext (tatsächlich gegeben oder aus der Erfahrung ergänzt) und Konvention ab.

> Das Paar sitzt im Auto.

Wir haben ein Singular-Objekt und fassen damit die beiden Menschen als Einheit auf. Sie passen auch beide gut hinein – es gibt einfach keinen Grund anzunehmen, dass sie nicht im selben Auto sitzen. Ebenso bezeichnet "Panzerbesatzung" die Besatzung *eines* Panzers - warum also sollten sie in mehreren sitzen? In beiden Fällen wird der Satz mit *im* eindeutig mit einem Fahrzeug verstanden, so lange Du nicht einen Kontext mitlieferst, der zu mehreren Fahrzeugen führt. (Und das dürfte ohne große Verrenkungen schwierig werden.)

> Die Herde ist im Stall.

Ohne weiteren Kontext wird man auch hier an einen Stall denken. Aber wenn die Herde groß ist und der Bauer sie in zwei Ställen unterbringt, wird der Bauer trotzdem diesen Satz verwenden (und nicht "... in den Ställen"), um am Abend auszudrücken, dass alle Kühe unter Dach und Fach sind. Und wenn ich abends zu meiner Frau sage

> Endlich liegen die Kinder im Bett.

fällt es schon mal durch den Plural leichter, an mehrere Betten zu denken, und außerdem wissen wir ja, dass jedes sein eigenes hat.

Da *im* eigentlich eine Zusammenziehung von *in dem* ist, sollten diese Beispiele theoretisch alle auch genauso mit *in dem* funktionieren. Bei grammatikalisch weiblichen Objekten ist das auch so (d.h. die Interpretation hängt von Konvention und Kontext ab):

> Das Paar sitzt in der Badewanne. (beide in derselben)
>   Das Paar liegt in der Hängematte. (wahrscheinlich in derselben, vielleicht aber auch zwei Matten nebeneinander?)
>   Die Matrosen liegen in der Hängematte. (ziemlich sicher jeder in seiner)

Praktisch ist es aber so, dass wir fast immer (? mir fällt jedenfalls kein Gegenbeispiel ein) *im* verwenden, wenn das *dem* in *in dem* als Artikel gebraucht wird. (Sprich: so wie sie dastehen, wirken Deine beiden "in dem"-Beispiele auf mich konstruiert. In der [Antwort von tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/36358/9091) werden die verschiedenen in Frage kommenden Wortarten eingehender thematisiert.) Und damit bleibt für "in dem", wenn es denn im tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch auftaucht, nur noch die Variante mit Demonstrativ-
oder Relativpronomen, in der es aber immer auf ein Singularwort verweist. Das ist meiner Meinung nach der Grund, warum Du annimmst, dass es in Deinen Beispielen einen unterschiedlich großen Interpretationsspielraum zwischen den beiden Varianten gibt. Er wäre tatsächlich vorhanden, wenn das *dem* betont wäre und es plausibel wäre, den Satz wahlweise mit einem Singular- oder Pluralobjekt zu verwenden:

> Alice und Bob liegen in **dem** Bett. (Schau, das große da drüben. Eindeutig Singular.)